# Cloning element in for loop breaks and runs forever

Tags: javascript, for-loop, clone

I want to get all elements (`svgs`) that have a specific class and clone them inside a div.

```
const images = document.getElementsByClassName('image_svg'); // collection of all elements (around 5 or so of them)
const myDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('myDiv')[0];

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var clone = images[i].cloneNode(true);
    myDiv.appendChild(clone);
}
```

When I execute my code, it runs forever and the browser stops responding.  What am I doing wrong here?

Note, this is a pure JS solution, so no jQuery answers please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a ***live*** collection.

Try with [`Document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> The Document method `querySelectorAll()` returns a static (***not live***) NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors.
>
> The Document method `querySelector()` returns the first Element within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

```
const images = document.querySelectorAll('.image_svg'); // collection of all elements (around 5 or so of them)
const myDiv = document.querySelector('.myDiv');
```